# Using numpy (and others module)

Tags: python-3.x

It's maybe a stupid thing, but I can't resolve it.

I used pip3 to install numpy, scipy... When I rewrote the instruction in command line, it said that

> "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   (1.16.2)"

But when I used Python 3.7.2 it said that

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"

So that I cannot use numpy actually. I tried also to remove python, and reinstall it via brew. But nothing happen.

Also, I've got a problem with pip. When I do `pip3 install --upgrade pip`, it answers

```
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: what does `import sys; print(sys.path)` say?

Comment: ['', '/Users/gautierhanna/Documents', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Comment: have you tried `pip install --upgrade pip` not `pip3`?

Comment: yes, but the command is not found

Comment: Quick and dirty fix would be to add `sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')` before `import numpy`. I don't know macos, so I can't tell you how to fix it properly.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But as I understand, this is a temporally solution, since I need to use this command everytime that I need to import something ?

But what happened exactly ?

Comment: Ugh, python environments are too complicated for anyone to tell you for sure...best advice is to delete your env and start over. Or use conda!

Comment: Well, you'd have to add the `sys.path.append(...)` in each script you want to use `numpy` from. It will at best confuse other people when you share the code and you won't be able to run other people's code without modifications. You should add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages` to the python search path or install your packages to a directory contained in `sys.path`. As I said, I don't know how to do that on mac. I'm sure you'll find something by googling for 'mac', 'python', 'import', 'search path', etc.

Comment: Thanks you very much !